# PHP: upload file upon selecting it but do not submit all the form

Tags: php, forms, upload, submit

I have a form with several required fields (name, phone no., etc...) and a field for selecting a file to submit.

1. Is is possible to upload this file right away upon selecting it without submitting the form? (it resides in the same  element as the rest of the fields.
2. How to handle the case when the file is being uploaded and the whole form is submitted at the same time? I am far from skilled in PHP so... won't it break something?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes this is possible but first let me ask what is the purpose of this, because you may not really need to.

Comment: @php_nub_qq I think the OP already has his/her mind set behind `the idea`. Hidden agendas are not our concern.

Comment: @Fred I am asking because if the OP wants to create a dynamic profile picture changer type of thing then the image can be loaded via javascript to preview and then uploaded when form is submitted. Also, your idea of uploading an image via Ajax will give them a really hard time.

Comment: @php_nub_qq Sure I agree there, however, Javascript alone can't take care of the uploading part. It probably could load an image if it's from a set of pre-determined images, but it won't upload. It just seems trickier to load with Javascript then pass it over to PHP to do the work. Whilst with Ajax, you could do both from the same file.

Comment: @Fred Yeah but if multiple images are to be previewed, assuming that one is going to be uploaded, that's just wasting resources. Let's quit this discussion and wait for the OP to respond and see what they really want! :P

Comment: @php_nub_qq Actually that's a good idea. If it is doable by JS there is no need to upload it before. Can I access the filename/content using JS?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat function you can use to dynamically preview images, **without uploading them**, using javascript. I believe this is cross-browser, but I cannot confirm on 100%. I have gotten this code a long time ago and it was not originally written by me, however I have made some modifications for it to fit my needs, which include jQuery. If you do not use jQuery in your application then you'll have to change a few things. Anyway here's the function:

```
var loadImageFile = (function () {
    if (window.FileReader) {
        var oPreviewImg = null, oFReader = new window.FileReader(),
            rFilter = /^(?:image\/bmp|image\/cis\-cod|image\/gif|image\/ief|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/pipeg|image\/png|image\/svg\+xml|image\/tiff|image\/x\-cmu\-raster|image\/x\-cmx|image\/x\-icon|image\/x\-portable\-anymap|image\/x\-portable\-bitmap|image\/x\-portable\-graymap|image\/x\-portable\-pixmap|image\/x\-rgb|image\/x\-xbitmap|image\/x\-xpixmap|image\/x\-xwindowdump)$/i;
        var curImgPreview, curInput;

        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            var tempImg = new Image();
            tempImg.onload = function(){
                curImgPreview.attr('src',oFREvent.target.result);
            }
            tempImg.src = oFREvent.target.result;
        };

        return function (inputOBJ, outputOBJ) {
            var aFiles = inputOBJ.files;
            curInput = $(inputOBJ);
            curImgPreview = outputOBJ;
            if (aFiles.length === 0) { return; }
            if (!rFilter.test(aFiles[0].type)) { Alert("Please select a valid image file."); return; }
            oFReader.readAsDataURL(aFiles[0]);
        }

    }
    if (navigator.appName === "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
        return function () {
            otuputOBJ.filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").src = inputOBJ.value;

        }
    }
})();
```

Then on your input that is of type file you add

`<input onchange='loadImageFile(this,$(HTMLimgObject))'/>`

Where the second parameter is the img object you want to preview the image file in.

Hope everything works well for you,

Good luck!